# PHP read file from network folder System Error 86

Tags: php, networking, filesystems

I'm trying to read some files in this folder: "Z:\2022" in my network shared folder.
But i'm getting this error:

"The specified network password is invalid."

This is what i'm trying

```
<?php

$path = '\\\\10.0.X.X\2022'; 

$user = "10.0.X.X/Administrator";
$pass = "";
$drive_letter = "Z";


echo '<br><br>';
$str = "net use ".$drive_letter.": \"".$path."\" '".$pass."' /user:'".$user."' /persistent:no 2>&1";
echo 'RESULT: '.shell_exec($str); // Returns "The specified network password is invalid".

$location = $drive_letter.":/2022";

if ($handle = opendir($location)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    echo "$entry";
    } 
    closedir($handle);
}
else {
    echo 'FALSE'; // Output
}

?>
```

So, should I specify wifi password or computer password?

Comment: definitely not wifi.  That's only for connecting to the wifi network.  It has no bearing on any other network stuff

Comment: Thanks, in theory the shared drive has no password, but I found a password for that IP in the windows credentials, could it be that?